# FB Automatic Wall Post

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've implemented Wall post on the loggedin user with Graph API, its working fine i want if user clicks any button on my website(for eg if he purchase any thing) this will published on his wall,below is my code but in this code it is opening Publish dialog and i want to publish automaticallly(offcourse only when he logged in with fb and already has authorized)

```
FB.ui(
{
method: 'feed',
name: 'Transaction succeeded',
link: 'http://abc.com/', 
description: 'Success'
},
function(response) {
if (response && response.post_id) { 
} else { 
}
}
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`FB.api`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/) to post feed stories once user is authorized and granted `publish_stream` permission to your application:

```
FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', {
  name: 'Transaction succeeded',
  link: 'http://abc.com/', 
  description: 'Success'
}, function(response) {
  if (!response || response.error) {
    alert('Error occured');
  } else {
    alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried this code,but its showing Error occured then IIS stopped working this hapening each time i am executing this code

Comment: @SyedSalmanRazaZaidi, this code have nothing to do with IIS, It's a JavaScript that should be running on client-side (as well as the code sample you provided) the only requirement for this code to run is Facebook JavaScript SDK. What error you get? Do your user have granted `publish_stream` persmission?

Answer (score 0):

You can publish to the Facebook graph by issuing HTTP POST requests to the appropriate connection URLs, using an access token. For example, you can post a new wall post on XYZ's wall by issuing a POST request to https://graph.facebook.com/XYZ/feed:

```
curl -F 'access_token=...'  -F 'message=Hello, XYZ. I like this new API.' 
  https://graph.facebook.com/XYZ/feed
```

you can use curl request in .net